# HTML display client list

Tags: html, list, select

I am developing a website and have a facility where the user can search for a client and a list of possible matching clients is returned in an array. I want to display the list so that the user can then click on the correct client, which will take them to a client update page.

What is the best way of displaying this list of clients? Would I use a [select tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) and go through the array appending each client?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: For a small number of clients a select will work fine, however once the list gets large it can get unwieldy; at that point you might want to consider one of the various autocomplete options e.g. [jQueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A select tag would create a drop down, instead of the list that you would like to display.

I would suggest doing something like this :

```
<form>
<table>
<!-- use your looping logic here -->
<tr><td> client name</td></tr>
<button> Submit button</button>
</table>
```

If you don't want to go through the hassle of creating a table, you can use the `<li>` tag instead.

Comment: Thanks. How does this allow the user to click on the client's name?

Comment: You will need to add an additional button / radio box to click onto and send the clicked client's name or id to server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, If you are using just vanilla JavaScript then you can do the way you thought of. Otherwise you can use some lite javascript frameworks like AngularJs or VueJs which could make your work a lot less time consuming.